# Apache nifi Evalutejson path

Tags: json, apache-nifi

```
{"data":["12345","IND","899","Tammy","clininc","44444","IND","444","Tammm2","clinic1","95","Exact"]}
```

I have the above JSON data and want

```
12345 as one value
IND as another value
899 as another value and so on
```

Can I use `$.data[0]` to get `12345`, `$.data[1]` to get IND in EvaluteJson Path processor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahmed,

You can have Array of values in JSON using EvaluateJSONPathProcessor.

In that processor you have to change "Destination" attribute in that to be "flowfile-attribute".

After that add newer attribute in **EvaluateJsonPathProcessor** to access those values you want like below.

```
data.0:$.data[0]
data.1:$.data[1]
data.2:$.data[2]
```

Then you can use those extracted values like below.,

```
${data.0} 
${data.1}
${data.2}
```

It work for me.

Feel free to upvote/accept this to be answer if it work for you.